# calculating differences within groups

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a `DataFrame` whose rows provide a value of one feature at one time. Times are identified by the time column (there's about 1000000 distinct times). Features are identified by the feature column (there's a few dozen features). There's at most one row for any combination of feature and time. At each time, only some of the features are available; the only exception is feature 0 which is available at all times. I'd like to add to that `DataFrame` a column that shows the value of the feature 0 at that time. Is there a reasonably fast way to do it?

For example, let's say I have

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
  'time': [1,1,2,2,2,3,3],
  'feature': [1,0,0,2,4,3,0],
  'value':[1,2,3,4,5,6,7],
})
```

I want to add a column that contains [2,2,3,3,3,7,7].

I tried to use `groupby` and boolean indexing but no luck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I'd like to add to that DataFrame a column that shows the value of the feature 0 at that time. Is there a reasonably fast way to do it?

I think that a `groupby` (which is quite an expensive operation) is an overkill for this. Try a `merge` with the values only of the 0 feature:

```
>>> pd.merge(
        df,
        df[df.feature == 0].drop('feature', axis=1).rename(columns={'value': 'value_0'}))
    feature     time    value   value_0
0   1   1   1   2
1   0   1   2   2
2   0   2   3   3
3   2   2   4   3
4   4   2   5   3
5   3   3   6   7
6   0   3   7   7
```

---

**Edit**

Per @jezrael's request, here is a timing test:

```
 import pandas as pd

 m = 10000

 df = pd.DataFrame({
   'time': range(m / 2) + range(m / 2),
   'feature': range(m / 2) + [0] * (m / 2),
   'value': range(m),
 })
```

On this input, @jezrael's solution takes 396 ms, whereas mine takes 4.03 ms.

Comment: Can you add performance comparing your and my solution with large dataframe? Now I am only on phone, so I cant do it. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If you'd like to drop the zero rows and add them as a separate column (slightly different than your original request), you could do the following:

```
# Create initial dataframe.
df = pd.DataFrame({
  'time': [1,1,2,2,2,3,3],
  'feature': [1,0,0,2,4,3,0],
  'value':[1,2,3,4,5,6,7],
})

# Set the index to 'time'
df = df.set_index('time')

# Join the zero feature value to the non-zero feature rows.
>>> df.loc[df.feature > 0, :].join(df.loc[df.feature == 0, 'value'], rsuffix='_feature_0')
      feature  value  value_feature_0
time                                 
1           1      1                2
2           2      4                3
2           4      5                3
3           3      6                7
```

Answer (score 0):

You can [`set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) from column `value` and then [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) with [`transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html) [`idxmin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.idxmin.html).

This solution works, if the value `0` in column `feature` is `min`.

```
df = df.set_index('value')

df['diff'] = df.groupby('time')['feature'].transform('idxmin')
print df.reset_index()
   value  feature  time  diff
0      1        1     1     2
1      2        0     1     2
2      3        0     2     3
3      4        2     2     3
4      5        4     2     3
5      6        3     3     7
6      7        0     3     7
```

Comment: Per your request I timed it. By me, your solution works ~100 times slower.